# SpringBoot Hibernate, CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapping, hibernate-criteria

Is it possible to fetch Data from 3 tables in hibernate where the controller is of a different model.

`code`AModel.Java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="demo")
//@NamedQuery(name="Demo.findAll", query="SELECT m FROM Demo m")
public class AModel implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="demo_loc")
    private String location;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    public String getLocation() {
       return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

BModel.Java
@Entity
@Table(name="location")
//@NamedQuery(name="City.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM City c")
public class BModel implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="locationNoid")
    private int locationNoId;

    @Column(name="Code")
    private int Code;
    public int getLocationNoId() {
        return locationNoId;
    }
    public void setLocationNoId(int locationNoId) {
        this.locationNoId = locationNoId;
    }
    public int getCode() {
        return Code;
    }
    public void setCode(int code) {
        Code = code;
    }
}



CModel.java
@Entity
@Table(name="offers")
public class CModel implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int OfferShopid;

        @Column(name="offerCount")
        private int offerCount;

        @Column(name="foodCount")
        private int foodCount;

        public int getOfferShopid() {
        return OfferShopid;
        }
        public void setOfferShopid(int offerShopid) {
            OfferShopid = offerShopid;
        }
        public int getOfferCount() {
            return offerCount;
        }
        public void setOfferCount(int offerCount) {
            this.offerCount = offerCount;
        }
        public int getFoodCount() {
            return foodCount;
        }
        public void setFoodCount(int foodCount) {
            this.foodCount = foodCount;
        }


}




DemoDTO.java

public class LocationDTO {

    private int demoId;
    private String name;
    private int Code;
    private int foodCount;


    public int getDemoId() {
        return demoId;
    }
    public void setDemoId(int demoId) {
        this.demoId = demoId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getCode() {
        return Code;
    }
    public void setCode(int code) {
        Code = code;
    }
    public int getFoodCount() {
        return foodCount;
    }
    public void setFoodCount(int foodCount) {
    this.foodCount = foodCount;
    }
}


DemoController.java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/abcService")
@Api(description = "REST API to list details")

public class DemoController {
@Autowired
private DemoService DemoService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/list/v1/{user_id}/uid/{locationNoId}/location", 
method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@ApiOperation(value = "Get all Lists", notes = "Get all Address related 
information")
public ResponseEntity<?> getAll(@PathVariable("user_id") int userId, 
@PathVariable("locationNoId") int locationNoId)
{
    try {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<DemoDTO>>() {
        }.getType();
        List<DemoDTO> listAll=DemoService.ListAll(userId,locationNoId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(listAll, HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch (Exception ex){
        String errorMessage;
        errorMessage = ex.getMessage();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMessage, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
}
```

DemoDAOImpl

```
@Component
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DemoDAOImpl implements DemoDAO {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager; 

@Autowired
private AService aService;

AModel aModel;


@Override
public @ResponseBody List<DemoDTO> ListAll(int User_id, int locationNoId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



      List<DemoDTO> listDemo=new ArrayList<>();

      CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
      CriteriaQuery<AModel> query =
     criteriaBuilder.createQuery(AModel.class); Root<AModel> root =
      query.from(AModel.class); query.select(root); CriteriaQuery<AModel>
      select = query.select(root); TypedQuery<AModel> typedQuery =
      entityManager.createQuery(select); List<AModel> AllLists =
      typedQuery.getResultList();

      for(AModel listofAll :AllLists ) {
      System.out.println(listofAll.getid());
      System.out.println(listofAll.getname());
      System.out.println(listofAll.getlocation());
      System.out.println(listofAll.getid());
      System.out.println(listofAll.getRating()); 
      listMalls.(AllLists); 

      return listMalls;

}
```

Comment: Probably yes - could you give more details.

Comment: Okay. There are 3 controllers(A, B, C) where the CRUD operations are done successfully. But what i am trying to do is, creating another controller ( i.e D) and i want to retrieve data of (A, B,C) and display it.

Comment: So as i understand: 3 controllers(A, B, C) make this CRUD operation via other class (serive, repository) and they expose rest api as a public methods. Good way would be refactor all logic from controllers to service. For example controller A use service A. And then you can use this services (A, B, C) in your new controller D. Could you give some code of one of this controls, how one REST method now looks like?

Comment: @Iczapski i have shared a sample example.

Comment: OK, I see Entities and DTOs. But I want to see controllers something what have anotations: RestController o RequestMapping

Comment: Ok @Iczapski Sample controller has been shared..

Comment: Can you use this services in a way as I show below?

Answer (score 0):

Base `DemoController` you have already a DemoService that you can reuse between other controlers. So if you have

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/abcServiceA")
public class DemoControllerA {
    @Autowired
    private DemoServiceA demoServiceA;
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/abcServiceB")
public class DemoControllerB {
    @Autowired
    private DemoServiceB demoServiceB;
```

You can create controler:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/abcServiceB")
public class DemoControllerD {
    @Autowired
    private DemoServiceA demoServiceA;
    @Autowired
    private DemoServiceB demoServiceB;
```

Use this two services in one method:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/list/v1/{user_id}/uid/{locationNoId}/location",method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@ApiOperation(value = "Get all Lists", notes = "Get all Address related information")
        public ResponseEntity<?>getAll(@PathVariable("user_id")int userId,
        @PathVariable("locationNoId")int locationNoId) {
    try {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<DemoDTO>>() {}.getType();
        List<DemoDTO> listAllFromA = aemoServiceA.ListAll(userId, locationNoId);
        List<DemoDTO> listAllFromB = aemoServiceB.ListAll(userId, locationNoId);
        // do something with listAllFromA and listAllFromB
        return new ResponseEntity<>(listAll, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        String errorMessage;
        errorMessage = ex.getMessage();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMessage, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah it will display everything from AModel And BModel. This is fine. But what if i want certain type of parameters like for example i want to choose only one variable from a Model and retrieve it in DemoController.

Comment: If you 'want to choose only one variable from a Model' so why do not you just not create a dedicated method in `DemoService` and use it in controller. @Stunner_94

Comment: The DAO implementation i have shared can you check it make needful changs.

Comment: i am not sure if this code search by criterias: int User_id, int locationNoId.
You can use Spring data https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html or check it https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-repositories